# How i can Count the days from last_updated date to Today date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to show total number of days from last updated date to Today Date, I want to display these Days on my view file, Please let me know where i am mistaking.
Here is my view code...

```
<li><?php echo $this->lang->line('member_since'); ?> : <span class="pull-right"><?php 
                                 $date1= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
                                 $date2= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
                                 $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
                                 if(empty($diff))
                                 {
                                     echo "0 Day";
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
                                 }

                                ?></span></li>
```

Comment: your `$date1` and `$date1` both are last updated, there is no current date passed.

Comment: I want to count the days between `last_updated` date to current time...

Comment: try this `$date1= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
                                 $date2= date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Still 0 Day Counting..

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
```

You assigned the same variable `$customer['last_update']` to `$date1` and `$date2`.

Comment: Please use one variable `$customer['last_update']` and let me count the days between this date to current time...

Comment: You need to change it like this `$date2 = date('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 1):

change your $date2 to today's time

```
    <li>
    <?php echo $this->lang->line('member_since'); ?> : <span class="pull-right"><?php 
                                     $date1= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
                                     $today= date('Y-m-d');
                                     $diff=date_diff($date1,$today);
                                     if(empty($diff))
                                     {
                                         echo "0 Day";
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                         echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
                                     }

                                    ?></span></li>
```

Comment: can you give us a sample input

Comment: `2019-04-30 22:52:04`, it's last_updated field value in my DB

Answer (score 1):

try this,

> you forgot to compare with today's date in your code

```
$date1= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($customer['last_update']));
$today= date('Y-m-d');
$diff=date_diff($today,$date1);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");die;
```

> date_diff will returns a DateInterval object on success that represents the difference between the two dates. FALSE on failure

Comment: are you inserting date like this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` or `date('Y-m-d h:i:s');`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in MySQL using the following query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( now(), '2019-08-05' ) as days;
```

you can pass your column name(last_updated) instead of '2018-08-05'.

So instead of doing it in PHP, you can do it while fetching it from the database.